# Can't Learn Recipes At The Diner

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When I go to restaurants how do I get Ignis to write down the new recipe? Do you need the ingredients already?

Right now I am going to the restaurants and buying the food, but for some reason he doesn't learn the recipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignis wont learn many recipes from restaurants.

There are four main ways Ignis learns recipes.

1. Increasing his cooking level, which means camping (and helps Gladio)
2. Being inspired by events that happen when you search or investigate things
3. Buying them at a shop
4. Collecting all the ingredients for a complete meal from the leaf icons on your map